# C# HOW TO EXECUTE GO QUERY

Tags: c#

How to run a GO query on C#. Below are my query

```
            sqlConnection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = ("USE Repository" +
                               "GO" +

                               "DECLARE     @return_value int," +
                                           "@o_error_code int," +
                                           "@o_error_msg varchar(2000)" +

                               "EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[XCENTER_CUST_CREATE_UPDATE]" +
                                           "@i_input_xml = N'<xml code>'," +
                                           "@i_transaction_id = N'100A'," +
                                           "@o_error_code = @o_error_code OUTPUT," +
                                           "@o_error_msg = @o_error_msg OUTPUT" +

                               "SELECT      @o_error_code as N'@o_error_code'," +
                                           "@o_error_msg as N'@o_error_msg'" +

                               "SELECT      'Return Value' = @return_value" +

                               "GO");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            DT1.DataSource = dt;
```

This is to run after I pressed button and the value of xml code is in the textbox

Answer (score 1):

`GO` is not a T-SQL command. It is only recognized by some tools as a batch separator. See the documentation (under remarks)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

This means that you can only use it from like SSMS or sqlcmd or some of the tools that recognize it.

Comment: so it is not possible? :(

Comment: You can use the SMO dll-s associated with SSMS. Check (this blog): https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way